# Preventing serial down voting when almost every question seems to show no research?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

I'm wondering what we are to do now that massive amounts of questions "show no research." My basic concern is if I keep downvoting I'm going to get flagged, which makes me want to simply stay off Stack Overflow completely, but that really goes against what I used to (and somewhere still do) believe about this community.

I mean, we're supposed to downvote them when they show no research, but what's "showing research" anyway; it's pretty subjective.

How is "serial downvoting" flagged?

A perfect example in my opinion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148781/how-do-i-make-the-connection-between-mongodb-and-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-applic

Comment: Serial voting only applies if you target a specific user. If you're just downvoting all the junk (from all users), it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: On the contrary, this is your civic duty. :)

Comment: Maybe one day we will worry about *many of us* targeting a *specific* user, a.k.a. the Meta Effect. See it in action right now. *(Ah, you cannot see it anymore unless you have 10k rep already. Looks like the questioner anticipated the effect.)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Then everything that ends on Reddit will trip it. :)

Comment: @Mysticial, I wouldn't know, but if it attracts the same kind of attention then definitely yes :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, are you referring to a specific post?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud He's referring to the post linked in this question

Comment: I don't think that "showing no research" is subjective. It is down to the OP to demonstrate some effort, by explaining what they have tried and providing some relevant code. If they don't do this then we have to assume that they haven't expended any energy. Who wants to waste time trying to squeeze information from them when down-votes and/or closing provide a clear message?

Comment: Is there a new "shows no research" close reason available now?

Comment: @JK. If you hover over the down arrow it states no research.

Comment: Ah right, got it. BTW I doubt that any new user who doesn't care enough to write a good question will make any connection between receiving a downvote and realizing that someone is saying they have not done enough research.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Serial voting is the act of voting on a series of posts *by a specific user*. Say, you visited my profile because you are upset with one of my comments (don't look so surprised, it happens), and voted down everything in sight, or voted everything *up* because you like my cuddly Ninja.

When voting on posts by different users, you are not voting serially, and no automatic reversal will take place.

Vote away!

Comment: It should also be pointed out that there's no automatic system flag for serial voting, and the only time there are any consequences is when a moderator steps in. We can examine the data and only act if there's apparent malice or some other kind of gaming going on, and even there it usually has to be pretty bad or obvious.

Comment: @Servy I would appreciate that more if you had a pirate avatar.

Comment: And with the new, longer wait period for asking another question, it's much less likely you'll come across many bad questions by the same user in a short period of time. I think I've accidentally serially downvoted someone back when the limit was shorter.

Comment: I fell a strong urge to upvote all your answers... ninjas are cool.

Comment: @BradLarson: it is not true that there is no automatic system for reversing serial voting - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/  (unless this has been recently reversed?)

Comment: @GreenAsJade I'm pretty sure the article only mentions strengthening the serial voting detection system.

Comment: @justcool393 "This happens automatically as part of a daily script, and it’s worked well to date, nullifying the most egregious upvoting and downvoting anomalies."   "If you see a reputation drop today, it’s likely because our new, improved daily vote anomaly check found something that should be removed".   There's another answer somewhere where it says "if you are upset about being downvoted, please wait 24 hours for the automatic system to detect it and reverse it before complaining", or something like that - I just can't find it right now!

Comment: @GreenAsJade: No, Brad is talking about *moderator flags*; when votes are reverted moderators are not auto-alerted to this.

Comment: @GreenAsJade - What Martijn said. We see a lot of people getting concerned that the system will automatically suspend or ban them if it picks up serial votes, and I wanted to make sure people knew that wasn't the case. We're not even flagged on instances where the system rolls back votes (which it only does in the worst cases), and something has to be bad enough to catch our eye before we'll look into it. Suspensions are only handed out by humans, and we always take a good look before we do so.

Comment: Surely when a user posts an answer that is rubbish, it is likely that their other answers may be rubbish too, and it's a community service to inspect them, and vote accordingly?

Comment: @podiluska: then trust the community to do their job. It is not *your job alone*. You cannot go through another person's post history and downvote everything is sight, that'll be reverted automatically, as there is no way to distinguish between your well-intentioned quality control action and a revenge downvote spree.

Answer (score 6):

If a particular users will post an immense amount of crap in some tag, and you downvote that all (more that 2 a day) than that downvotes will be reverted without warning.

Leaving **comments** and voting to **close** is more efficient. Yeah, and it helps to write down/mark the names of the people whose posts you downvote because of no research, just to prevent downvoting them too much (which will, be design, be counterproductive).

I normally don't downvote while reviewing queues. I'll run out votes, and I want to spare some to upvote good content.

Answer (score 2):

The longer SO is extant, the more the "shows no research." problem becomes applicable - since more and more questions now have answers on SO, SO itself becomes a place to do research before you ask your question. The result is that many questions that might have been good ones a few years ago are now dups or "show no research".

So IMO it becomes increasingly difficult to ask good questions unless on something very new and cutting edge or esoteric. If that is why your your tendency "is to keep downvoting"? perhaps take time to explain why, and mitigate concerns about your being a "serial downvoter". (I think that's the best policy, regardless.)

Comment: Good point. When I see some of the older, more basic SO questions with tons of upvotes I often wonder if they'd be so well received if asked today. I think this can be misleading.

Comment: @aw04: The user base has grown much larger and more discriminating, so there are more hard questions with good answers - the bar is continually being raised. I think SO would soon be obsolete except as a knowledge base if not that technology keeps moving forward, so there is always unexplored territory. A question on  `Go` for example, will generally be well received because `Go` is new and not used all that much. But if want to ask something about `C++` 99% of the time an answer is already here someplace-if I ask, it will get closed as a dup or "answer found here", and often downvoted.

Comment: Yes it's a predictable and fundamental change, really. A lot of questions on here about how to react to more and more bad questions on SO, not enough asking why the ratio of good to bad has changed so dramatically and what to do about it moving forward IMO.

Comment: @aw04 - _not enough asking why the ratio of good to bad has changed_ -true. I think the reason is that neophytes do a google search, see that SO is a site for asking programming questions (there are so many answers here that SO comes up in google on anything about programming you search for) and they just get on here and put up a question, without thinking about it. And yes, it is quite predictable on a site of this scope/size with a massive expert user base. It's a Catch 22 situation that happens on a lot of very successful sites of this nature: Quality is inversely proportional to Scale.

Comment: A catch 22 indeed, and from a business standpoint as well. You want traffic on the site, but as you correctly stated earlier it's becoming harder and harder to ask a good question with so many having already been answered, and punishing bad questions can turn users away. It will be interesting to see how they choose to address this going forward, if at all. Great discussion btw.

Comment: @aw04 -  _It will be interesting to see how they choose to address this going forward, if at all_ - LOL - as in any such situation, **the bottom line** will determine how they address it going forward... _Great discussion btw_ - very old denizen of the internet here - from before anybody dreamed of the WWW... enjoy.

Comment: @aw04- _can turn users away_ : That's a biggie IMO. I almost never downvote new users for bad questions - I edit/answer if possible, and maybe comment on the quality of the question. The point is to educate, not discourage. "Purists" get peeved because bad questions "diminish the quality of the site" ,  but in the end this happens to be the wild and wooly **public internet.**  If they're looking for purity, they can pay money and subscribe to a peer-reviewed academic sites, etc.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Everyone deserves a chance to learn and grow and become part of an open community. I've asked questions that in hindsight were less than optimal and will probably do so again but I always appreciate the more experienced users who take the time to help me to understand why and I try to do the same for others.

Comment: @Vector: Just because SO is free to use doesn't automatically mean it should cater to every Tom, Dick and Harry wanting to use it to learn their craft. Quite the contrary: newbies should buy a book, enroll on a course etc. It is they who should be paying to gain marketable skills, not us who should be paying to have a useful, meaningful, informative Q&A to spread actual knowledge of _actual_ problems. Answering low-quality gubbins just encourages more of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - with a name like _LightnessRacesinOrbit_ I'm surprised you don't have a better grasp of **relativity.** :)

Comment: _...it should cater to every Tom, Dick and Harry..._  - I think therein lies your mistake: Being a public site, SO is whatever the user base and market forces make it into. If you are naive enough to believe that at some point the people running this apparently lucrative enterprise will shut it down because it is now dominated by _every Tom Dick and Harry_ although it is bringing in nice revenue, then I have in bridge in Brooklyn I'd like to sell you. On your profile: _contributing to the complete devastation of our profession._ (continued...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - 20 years ago many thought that GUI based IDE's would _devastate our profession_ - you no longer had to learn all the nuances of compiling, linking, make files. That didn't pan out... Since you are apparently a seasoned pro, you naturally see things devolving - you feel you had to do much more work to get to where you are than does someone breaking into the field now. I also can view things that way if I cared to. (continued...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - But it's fallacious: The scope of software-its distribution, its importance, its uses, has increased exponentially in that time, so naturally the way things are done also changes and there are more developers out there at different levels looking to break in: All those _Tom, Dick and Harry's_ of yours...

Comment: `Being a public site, SO is whatever the user base and market forces make it into.` Absolute rubbish. The owners of this site know what is best for its community, and they know how easy it would be to lose all the question-answering experts that keep it viable, and they have a backbone. That is why there are like 20 meta discussions from the past few months where the mods and devs _explicitly recognise this_ and find ways to combat it. You _cannot_ defend an influx of poorly-researched rubbish by claiming that it's all down to evolution of the trade and we _must_ cater for it. What nonsense!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The strength of moderators' backbones is in the end determined by the bottom line... If those paying the bills decide that moderators should have "less backbone", that's what will happen, or the site will shut down or the format will change. "Follow the money" is the only rule applicable.

Comment: @Vector: I said "mods and devs". This isn't an imaginary policy constructed by ignorant fools with no idea of what Stack Exchange Inc. thinks; this is real policy, stated repeatedly by people some of whom are employed directly by Stack Exchange. I'm not just making it up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Regardless: **Follow the Money.**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -  I am not advocating a lower quality site. But at a certain point such a site must of necessity  evolve into a more of a knowledge base than a Q/A site, if not for new technologies emerging that give rise to new questions. That means that there is less room for participation by expert veterans of older technologies - their job has already been done. (continued...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I don't see the point of bemoaning the fact that allowing neophytes to ask questions is "contributing to the destruction of our profession", although yes, it does diminish the quality of the site. I'd venture that the number of "bad questions" is a function of the age of the technology under discussion. As a C++ veteran, you feel the pain more. Regardless, no matter how many times you ask "plz debug my code" on SO, you're not going to cut it doing that on a real job, so I don't think "our profession" is in danger.

Comment: @Vector: Are you kidding? Using SO to debug your work for you — work you're being paid to do — is _exceedingly_ commonplace! Our profession is in danger because there is a whole new generation or two of software developers who have no idea whatsoever how to debug their code.

Comment: `But at a certain point such a site must of necessity evolve into a more of a knowledge base than a Q/A site` Nope, it's whatever the owners say it is, as you said yourself. And stop going on about money.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit- (BTW - it's not a "profession" but a trade or "highly skilled labor" or "artisan"-you don't need any particular degree or license to be a programmer.) "stop going on about money" - I will, if you agree to pay all my bills. :) "Our profession is in danger because there..." why does this sound alarmist to me? Where are these programmers who don't know how to debug that are making it difficult for serious code jockeys to make a living? I've never worked a job where someone like that would last more than a day. Of course, I do work jobs that pay more than $10 an hour...