# What do we do when we see massive downvoting on posts in a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Today, when I've visited Stack Overflow as always to see the newest [AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) questions, I've noticed that a lot of question had a negative score. After a closer look, it appeared that even the positively-scored questions have also got a downvote. Actually, all the questions between 08:10:00Z and 11:00:00Z (roughly 35 questions) have received a downvote.

This is very strange, and so I suspect this is the act of a single person. Is such behaviour allowed? I mean, this guy has probably downvoted without really paying attention to the questions, since even the good ones were downvoted, so we are not really in the situation of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/preventing-serial-down-voting-when-almost-every-question-seems-to-show-no-resear).

If it's not allowed, how should I have reacted? I've flagged one of the relevant question as "need moderator attention" while explaining the problem, but the flag was declined.

Comment: If this was done by a single actor it will be automatically corrected by the serial down-vote correction widget.

Comment: No, "serial voting is when one person votes on a single person's posts, not one person voting on many posts as they come in", right? I've used the term "serial downvoting" in my flag and it was declined with this explanation, actually. I suppose I've badly chosen my words.

Comment: Hmmmmm...maybe so @Blackhole. I'm not sure if the serial down-voting correction mechanism looks just at the actor and receiver, or if it is more broad.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: no, the serial voting script will not correct votes across a series of posts related by tag, only across a series of posts *by the same author*.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MartijnPieters. I guess that leaves the OP's question wide-open. Is there a mechanism for that? Since voting is anonymous there would not be anything that could be flagged.

Comment: Even *if* this was done by a single actor it will not be prevented. Yes, this means someone with a bad day downvoting all angular questions because they don't like angular *is permitted*. Voting is a personal choice, as long as it is not used as an attack on another individual.

Comment: I had a look, but none of the downvoted questions are great ones.  My overriding impression is that they are being asked by folks learning the hot new thing and stumbling around in the dark a bit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, "good question" is maybe a bit exagerated. Let's say "not-so-bad question" instead :P. But I see tons of question "asked by folks learning the hot new thing and stumbling around in the dark a bit" every day on this tag, and that the first time I came across this massive downvoting behaviour.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've seen this behavior in other tags as well, is there a course of action in the broader sense (not limited to this specific example).

Comment: @apaul34208: Ask better questions.  On a more serious note, the moderator tools won't even recognize this kind of behavior.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous. We should refrain from making assumptions that a single user downvoted.

Comment: I seem to recall [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) does a lot of down voting. I think he's the [number one down voter](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/184902/votes-upvote-to-downvote-ratio) on the site according to one statistic. I would be amused if the system flagged and banned him.

Comment: @jww are you *kidding* me? He's only cast about 1500 downvotes. You want to see a true champ downvoter? Take a look at [Wooble](http://stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble).

Comment: @Cupcake, jww: Yeah, Eric Lippert has the greatest down:up *ratio*, not the greatest absolute number of downvotes.

Comment: @BoltClock Eric has high standards. I wonder who was lucky enough to receive the one upvote?

Comment: @Cupcake: He said in a comment elsewhere that it was an accident and now even he has forgotten which post he voted on.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit the question (edit is greyed out) but I think that the title is misleading.   The body of the question doesn't asked about "massive downvoting" - which is the question JasonC answers.   It asks about one poster downvoting lots of questions in a tag.  The asker is asking "how should I do my community bit to make sure that people don't indiscriminately downvote a bunch of questions in a tag apparently without concern to whether they are good questions or not".  The title doesn't say that though.

Comment: @BoltClock I think he actually can see his single upvote via the URL http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=votes&sort=upvote (Tab votes, with subtab "upvotes")

Comment: @MaximeLorant I guess he just wanted to prevent division by zero when calculating the ratio. ;)

Comment: The downvote is almost ruining this site. I try to avoid ask question in popular tags unless I rushing to get my job done. The reason is probably too many high scores users in popular tags and they earns high amount of reputation points and so some of them downvote without any loss.

Comment: @林果皞 down votes on questions are free anyway. Only downvoting answers cost rep (-1 to be precise).

Answer (score 44):

You ask *What do we do when we see massive downvoting on posts in a specific tag?* The first thing we should do is verify that this is actually happening. This is the type of thing that can very easily be affected by confirmation bias, and even legitimate runs of downvotes may not necessarily be out of the ordinary, they could simply be more noticeable when they happen.

[Numbers as of the last public data refresh show no significant bias towards](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215212/votes-per-tag) [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

In particular, in a list of all tags with more than 10 total votes ranked by decreasing percentage of downvotes, the [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag ranks 13383 out of 28704, putting it in the ~47th percentile.

By comparison to the top 10 most popular tags:

```
Rank    TagName     Count  UpVotes DnVotes TotVotes  UpPct  DownPct
====================================================================
1341    php        618251   688441  171428   859869  0.800  0.199
2185    mysql      263185   306216   60252   366468  0.836  0.164
2648    html       324511   448821   79761   528582  0.849  0.151
4347    java       686279  1279577  168925  1448502  0.883  0.117
4548    jquery     513189   680634   86992   767626  0.887  0.113
5291    javascript 666680  1127500  130906  1258406  0.896  0.104
5680    c++        306642   779966   86311   866277  0.900  0.100
6703    android    546839   818473   80372   898845  0.911  0.089
6890    c#         677119  1365577  130765  1496342  0.913  0.087
7615    python     327098   766970   68196   835166  0.918  0.082
...
13383   angularjs   47425    77055    3971    81026  0.951  0.049
```

I.e. it has a higher percentage of upvotes than the popular tags.

A [similar query, limited only to votes cast in the 7 days prior to the last refresh](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215220), shows similar results (results limited to tags that have received more than 2 votes), again placing angularjs in the 40-50th percentile (2581 of 6346), and below the popular tags:

```
Rank    TagName     Count  UpVotes DnVotes TotVotes  UpPct  DownPct
====================================================================
798     php        618251     2900    2054     4954  0.585  0.414
1008    mysql      263185     1318     682     2000  0.659  0.341
1337    html       324511     2357    1084     3441  0.685  0.315
1473    java       686279     6015    2352     8367  0.719  0.281
1490    jquery     513189     2940    1106     4046  0.727  0.273
1764    c++        306642     3211    1063     4274  0.751  0.249
1774    android    546839     4456    1437     5893  0.756  0.244
1797    javascript 666680     5950    1843     7793  0.764  0.236
1809    c#         677119     5143    1573     6716  0.766  0.234
2209    python     327098     3832     834     4666  0.821  0.179
...
2581    angularjs   47425     1289     204     1493  0.863  0.137
```

So it appears your observation may be suffering from a bit of bias of some sort, and the problem you describe does not exist. While we do see a slight increase over recent times it does not appear to be "massive".

Still, I have run [a quick query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215221) to obtain number of upvotes and downvotes by day for this tag. Here is an embarrassingly ugly chart in OOCalc showing % downvotes per day:

[image]

So, given all the above, this does show a recent increase in downvote rate per day. However, at least on cursory visual inspection, the increase does not appear to be particularly significant (but confirmation bias either way may affect our interpretations) - or at least we will have to observe over the next few weeks to see if the trend continues or if it is just normal variation. Note also that this chart compares % downvotes, not rank, and does not compare to overall downvote % - it may be of limited usefulness, for which I apologize.

I maintain that no particular reaction should be necessary. Even if recent times show a slight increase, this does not appear to be "massive" or particularly significant, and [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) certainly is *not* particularly worse than any other tag, even *if* there have been more down votes recently.

Comment: I think your numbers actually go against my argument that the downvotes are not unusual, since AngularJS tends to get more upvotes than downvotes, as a whole.

Comment: @Cupcake It also goes against my original hypothesis that AngularJS users aren't good at asking questions.

Comment: That may still actually be the case. Just because a question is popular, that doesn't also mean that it's actually a good or well-written question.

Comment: Besides [the comment of Cupcake](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267802/what-do-we-do-when-we-see-massive-downvoting-on-posts-in-a-specific-tag?noredirect=1#comment73011_267835), I think we can't really get any information of a global analysis of the tag; the problem I've reported has a very limited scope (< 100 questions), and so has little to no influence on the number you show, has it? I suppose a comparison between the ratio of unvoted questions from different days (or weeks?) could be interesting, but we haven't the data for today currently.

Comment: @Blackhole Cupcake's comment indicated an observation not a criticism. Anyways, [a similar query limited to only votes cast in the past 7 days](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215220) shows similar results (see edit). It's true that you are referring to a limited scope but that could also be why you are just noticing something right now, e.g. compare to thinking you have "good luck" because dice happened to roll in your favor a few times in a row: even though over all it's the same, you're certainly going to notice your "lucky streak".

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. I'm certain to interpret correctly what I've seen, but can't prove it until the next update of the data explorer… But anyway: actually, the goal of my question was to ask how to react if the situation I've described was a proved fact, not to effectively prove it.  The answer of @Cupcake was good in this regard, I don't know why he has deleted it.

Comment: FWIW, I think this answer is answering the question in the title, and demonstrates that there is no massive downvoting occuring at all, but doesn't answer the question in the body, which is "what should I do in response to my suspicion that there is a nutcase downvoting all the questions in a tag?"

Comment: -1 Interesting data, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Chris It is if you approach it as an XY problem, but yes.

Answer (score 41):

### The story of the user who woke up and found crap in his tag

Here's a story. One day, a user who frequents the AngularJS tag wakes up and logs in to Stack Overflow. On this particular morning, 35 new questions were posted that were only mediocre at best, and really poor quality crap at worst. Unhappy with all of the junk cluttering his feed, the user downvotes all the bad questions. All 35 of them. Later that afternoon, Blackhole here logs on to Stack Overflow, and finds that, "mysteriously", someone has downvoted a bunch of questions in the AngularJS tag!

### What is it about that scenario that you find so unusual?

You're assuming that just because a bunch of questions (that aren't even yours) seem to have gotten downvotes, that it must then be the act of some Evil User who went on a rampage through the system?

*Do you have any concrete evidence of that?*

A more plausible explanation is that multiple users are visiting these questions, and voting based on whether they think the question is helpful and clear, or unhelpful and unclear, *just like they normally do*, on any question.

Even *if* it was a single user, **then so what?** As long as that user isn't serially targeting a single, specific user for downvotes, then they're free to express whatever they feel about a question through voting.

If a question really is useful, then it will garner more upvotes than downvotes over time, and things will just naturally sort themselves out that way.

Finally...

### Do *not* flag a moderator just because a bunch of questions in a tag get downvotes

This is a waste of the moderators' time. Downvotes happen, *they're a normal part of the democratic voting system* here at Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

Unless you can demonstrate that a single user is being repeatedly targeted for serial downvoting (by pointing out a [repeated pattern of obvious serial downvotes in a user's profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270/456814), or repeated serial downvoting reversal events), then don't flag a moderator to look into it.

Even if you can demonstrate that serial downvoting is occurring, consider if you want to bother a moderator about it, because serial downvotes are [automatically reversed by the system on a daily basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829) anyways.

Comment: Cool, that's a green light to commence downvoting all questions tagged with internet-explorer. I have an axe to grind with that hateful non-compliant browser...

Comment: @apaul34208 vote on *content* please, not on the specific technology that that content just so happens to be about `:P`

Comment: "A more plausible explanation is that multiple users are visiting these questions": that's really not a more plausible explanation. Come on, I've been checked this tag on a daily basis for more than one year; the majority of the new questions have no vote at all, ([check by yourself!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs?sort=newest)); and today, 30 successive questions are downvoted. What's the probability this happens in a normal way?

Comment: "Even if it was a single user, then so what?": that was the point of my question . [The comment of @apaul34208](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267802/how-to-react-about-massive-downvoting-on-an-unique-tag?noredirect=1#comment72842_267805) is willingly humorous, but, for you, it's perfectly permitted to do what he suggested?

Comment: @Blackhole users should vote based on the quality of the content that they find. If that content happens to be crap (in the eye of the beholder), then they're free to downvote it as such...again, as long as they're not repeatedly targeting a specific user.

Comment: @Blackhole regarding you anecdotal observations about this particular tag, you would have a more convincing argument if you backed them up with hard numbers from the [data.se] (SEDE).

Comment: I don't agree with the giant bolded bit.  If something seems fishy, I don't see what harm it does to flag one question for a moderator with the information that seems fishy.  Perhaps something wouldn't be done, but it seems to me like we'd rather people be a bit more flag happy than people just ignore things that seem fishy entirely; sort of like we'd rather people report suspicious people wandering about to the police than not, even if only 10% of them are criminals.

Comment: @Joe here's a story. One day, a user who frequents the AngularJS tag wakes up and logs in to Stack Overflow. On this particular morning, 25 new questions were posted that were only mediocre at best, and really poor quality crap at worst. Unhappy with all of the junk cluttering his feed, the user downvotes all the bad questions. All 35 of them. Later that afternoon, Blackhole here logs on to SO, and finds that, mysteriously(!), someone has downvoted a bunch of questions in the AngularJS tag! What is it about that scenario that you think sounds unusual?

Comment: If it seems odd to the user, then I think there's little harm in a single flag bringing it to the moderators' attention. Clearly it was odd enough to justify a question here, after all, and that wastes WAY more peoples' time, including several moderators'.

Comment: I think this answer nails it pretty much.   The only thing it doesn't explicitly say is that by upvoting the questions you think are worthy of it, you have done everything that is needed of individuals to counter a possible-tag-downvoting-nutcase.   Unlike a serial-author-downvoting-nutcase, a tag-downvoting-nutcase really can only achieve such limited damage anyhow.   When a person gets serially downvoted it really does them damage.  But when a bunch of questions in a tag all get downvoted by one person the impact is negiligible in real terms.  It's a "meh, who cares?" event.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think that you've been taking this "tag-downvoting-nutcase" theory a little too far. Like I said, it's more likely that one or more people just happened to find a bunch of crap in a tag one morning.

Comment: The question says "This is very strange, and so I suspect this is the act of a single person. Is such behaviour allowed?"   I just responded to that...

Comment: To be fair, the quality of the questions in the angularjs tag has taken a massive dive the last months. I suspect every single downvote was appropriate.

Comment: There are days I wish I could not just downvote a bunch of questions, but downvote many times a single one.

Comment: I've done this @Blackhole, and I know other people have. Watch the SQL tags at 8am GMT, the European mainland has arrived at work and the UK is starting to get in but no one has started asking questions yet. Everyone takes a quick flip through what the rest of the world has been doing for the past 8 hours; down votes and close a lot of it and answers the few gems. I know who'll be answering with me (quite sad I know)

Comment: +1 I occasionally go on a downvote/close vote spree in tags which tend to attract off-topic posts.  Come have a look in [tag:ubuntu] or [tag:debian] or [tag:postfix] or [tag:apache] some day (just to name a few).

Comment: -1: sorry, but if you can't be bothered into looking into something like that, then why are you a moderator? If a user asks you to look into something which is possibly odd you should look into it, and your explanations do not seem to me more plausible or more backed up with data than his ones.

Comment: @Chris I never said that they would. I said that voting from other users will naturally cause things to sort themselves out over time. Good posts will be upvoted, and bad posts will be untouched or continue to be downvoted, and eventually deleted.

Comment: @nico um, I'm *not* a moderator. Robert, who actually is, [has already taken a look](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267802/what-do-we-do-when-we-see-massive-downvoting-on-posts-in-a-specific-tag/267805#comment72802_267802) since this question was posted, and found nothing out of the ordinary. Not to mention, [as he pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267802/what-do-we-do-when-we-see-massive-downvoting-on-posts-in-a-specific-tag/267805#comment72806_267802), he doesn't even have the tools necessary to see something like this.

Comment: @nico **Downvoting happens**. As I've already pointed out, this is more likely than not just normal voting behavior, and thus a waste of moderators' time to look into. Do you really want [3.4 million registered users](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) to start flagging moderators every time they see downvoting happen?

Comment: @nico correction: there are only about [800k+ users with flagging privileges](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215855/number-of-users-with-privileges-for-x-reputation?MinRep=15), but still, that is not an insignificant number.

Comment: @Cupcake: for the moderator, sorry not sure why I thought you were. Downvoting happens, but if downvoting happens all of a sudden that is worth looking into. As for every single user flagging downvotes, no I do not want that. But a few users asking mods to look into some behaviour they think is not completely normal, yes I do want to be entitled to do that without someone telling me I am wasting mod time.

Comment: If there are a lot of crappy questions with the [tag:internet-explorer] tag, *please* downvote them, @apaul34208. But don't downvote questions just because you don't like the tech. I read Cupcake's answer again after seeing your comment just to be sure, and I don't see *anywhere* where he advocates this latter behavior.

Comment: @CodyGray I *think* his comment was just made in jest, but you can never be too sure...

Answer (score 7):

One person doing serial downvote on a questions of a tag - just because they are on the tag, not because they are bad question - is not "acceptable" but neither is it particularly significant, unless it's a very underused tag.

What's more, you can't tell, just by seeing a series of downvotes from a single person on a tag, whether they are downvotes for bad questions, or indiscriminate downvotes.

If the questions are genuinely bad, other people will also downvote. If the questions are actually OK, others *should* upvote, and you are doing your part if you have upvoted them.  That's all that you need to do. That should be enough to "counter" one serial downvoter nutcase. It would be a whole different kettle of fish if someone was achieving massive (more than one per question) down vote on a tag. But I don't think that is what you are talking about.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with downvoting a bunch of questions in a tag if you think they're bad questions. The only thing that's "unacceptable" is targeting a specific user with revenge downvotes.

Comment: @Cupcake I clarified what I meant by "serial downvote of questions on a tag".   Does address the reason for downvoting this answer?

Comment: I spend nearly all of my time in the [tag:git] tag. If one morning, I wake up and see a bunch of crappy questions in my favorite tag, and I downvote all of them, is that supposed to be "unacceptable"? I'm not downvoting because I hate Git (I love Git), I'm downvoting because I run into a bunch of crap questions in my favorite tag. How do you know that the AngularJS downvoter didn't also run into a bunch of crap questions (at least to him)?

Comment: @Cupcake It is certainly acceptable to downvote a bunch of questions that you have seen are crap on your favourite tag _becasuse_ they are crap.   This answer says that it is not acceptable to downvote them simply because they are on the tag, which is what the OP implies has happened.  I have further clarified this point.   Does that help?

Comment: Where else person would be doing up/downvoting? Indeed it is one (or small number) of tags that particular person watches. Voting on 30 questions in an hour or two on active tag like C#/PHP or even a bit less crazy angularjs does not sound like a stretch...

Comment: The curious thing about this discussion is that it appears to be refuting the premise of the question, rather than discussing a problem with this answer.   This answer assumes that the premise of the question is true: that someone has indiscriminately downvoted questions on the tag.   It addresses what should a person do about that?  That was the question.   The comments here appear to be challenging the idea that the indiscriminate downvoting has happened at all.  This answer tackles that as well: it acknowledges that you can't even tell if this is the case, so basically don't worry about it.