# How can Stack Overflow improve rule visibility and user experience?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rules

One of the most common complaints I get from other programmers when speaking of Stack Overflow is that the community seems to be "fanatical" and "puritans" about the Stack Overflow guidelines and rules.

From my experience, when I first came here I was excited by the concept, and it seemed rather magical to be able to have a group-think-tank on any given problem and achieve solutions you may not have even known were possible!

Unfortunately that was short lived, when on one of my questions I was rudely awoken to the seriousness of the Stack Overflow rules and community guidelines. I imagine that the moderator who struck me down was undoubtedly just doing his job, but their attitude (I'm not naming names) was abhorrent to any kind of respect and understanding. Instead of taking the time to educate me, they had just slapped the red tape on and moved on.

What I'm wondering, is it possible we have gone too far with moderating? If the general opinion of Stack Overflow in the programming community is negative, isn't that a pitfall for the site? Also, would it not be more entertaining/useful to have some kind of quiz on account creation to educate our new users on the basic guidelines and rules for posting?

Comment: In this case, it is probably for a) mistagging discussion as support b) beating a dead horse yet again. Anyway, this is meta, don't take it personally but learn from it (no rep to loose, only your good name ;-))

Comment: Mike, the problem that is likely attracting downvotes is _this has been beaten to death lately_. So everyone's likely getting tired of hearing/discussing how "bad/negative" SO is, or "how elitist" we are or things of that nature.

Comment: Stack Overflow is [**flooded with 7000-8000 *new* questions *per day***](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday). A lot of users and moderators aren't going to pamper each and every single post. They're going to process them, and move on to the next one.

Comment: Also, here's a Meta #ProTip, your *attitude* to how you approach things counts for a lot.

Comment: Might want to read some of the discourse on Meta Stack Exchange about this. There was kind of a spike of misunderstanding towards rules and regulations when the meta at Stack Overflow was wiped out.

Comment: Your answer was not deleted by a moderator, it was voted to be removed by 3 other SO users that have sufficient reputation to post such votes.  That was the correct thing to do, your post was not an answer.  Understanding the Q+A format and how SO is different from a forum is pretty basic.  Your meta post is a bit like getting pulled over by a police agent because you ran through a red stoplight and complaining that you didn't know that was required.  The Help Center is filled with good advice, you should read it thoroughly.

Comment: I just want to point out that you're upset over [an answer that must've taken you no more than a few seconds to write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668644/how-to-encode-a-string-using-c/20668688#20668688). How much time and effort did that really cost you? Personally, I'd be more upset if someone deleted something that I wrote that [looked like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/456814). Pick and choose your battles wisely.

Comment: I'm surprised that you all focussed on one small point I made, I don't care about my experience, I'm saying that this site has a general and negative public opinion. Honestly, I'm not surprised especially after this whole experiment. This question is a bad question too right? Honestly, I can't wait for something else to come and wipe SO away.

Comment: @Mike I think that [I addressed your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267955/456814) pretty directly. As for "waiting for something else to come and wipe SO away", there's a *very* long line for that, nothing that we haven't heard before. I [voted to reopen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/267950/revisions) your question because it was pretty fairly written and non-ranty, but I'd avoid starting off-topic rants in the comments, if you want to succeed here on Meta.

Comment: Meta tips: [How can I start a discussion critiquing the culture of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265419/456814).

Comment: I appreciate your links Cupcake, you seem to be the only person here who's actually trying to educate. Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I think [Brad gave a very fair and neutral answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267953/456814), but that's just my personal opinion. Also wanted to highlight [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/163250) since that one isn't actually closed. The MSO version shouldn't be closed either, since there's clear community consensus on how to approach discussions on Meta, but it's kind of a problematic post to begin with, if you look at its first revision.

Comment: "*This question is a bad question too right?*" Um, after looking this over again, it appears that you may not have been aware of the fact that, here on Meta, downvotes are often used to express disagreement, not that you wrote a bad question. Though, personally speaking, [I find downvotes on Meta to often be confusing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814).

Comment: Mike, the existence of people who think negatively about SO is a feature.  You cannot please everyone, nor should you try to.  If you are saying "there are people who want to use SO in ways that SO tries to prevent them from using SO", that is a not interesting statement.  Details (the ways they want to use it, and the ways they are prevented) could be interesting.  Stats could be interesting (I got 100 developers at my workplace to ask a question on stack overflow, and 79% of them said they would never do it again), especially with richness (and here are the questions).

Comment: And, in my experience, the general attitude towards stack overflow among the programmers I know is "it is great, much better than the old methods of trying to find programming answers online".  So, I dispute your claim that the general attitude towards stack overflow is negative.  So, given that your discussion is full of loaded negative words, contains assertions I find way off base, contains no hard examples of the problem you describe, what of interest are you saying again?  Add hard details (anecdote is better than nothing), groom your assertions, remove trollish language mayhap?

Comment: @Yakk leave Mike alone, this question is dead now, don't go digging up the corpse. Mike, if you want context, see [Can we make this meta site work for mentoring?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268790/456814).

Answer (score 25):

Can people on Stack Overflow be overzealous in applying the letter of the law, and lose perspective on why we're here? Yes. This is something that concerns me as well.

However, if I may comment on your specific example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668644/how-to-encode-a-string-using-c/20668688#20668688) was the answer you left:

> You're saying you want to obfuscate your strings?
>
> [Try this.](https://code.google.com/p/strenc/)

No moderators were involved in that answer, and you did receive two comments about why the answer was problematic:

> Please read stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers - link only answers aren't considered valid answers for Stackoverflow.

and

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

These did take the time to explain that particular convention on this site (one that I don't always agree with myself, but that's beside the point). Many of the standard review actions leave comments like this to inform people about problematic answers, and all question closure reasons have descriptions for why the question was closed. This isn't "slapping on red tape", it's an explanation of general site policy as determined by users here.

When it comes to the elected moderators, we try to warn or otherwise educate people as they are headed towards trouble on the site. Could we do a better job of presenting information to new users? Yes, we could, but that's constantly being worked on. It's certainly not my goal to lock people out, although some people here have become overly frustrated with the volume of bad content flooding the site and may overreact from time to time.

Comment: [7000-8000 *new* questions *per day*](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday)! `:/` All I found in my favorite tag this morning [was crap](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267805/456814). Shameless plug: [Stack Overflow Academy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy?referrer=bFkThEZ9P7sjquHM9dKpFQ2).

Comment: Re: "it's an explanation of general site policy as determined by users here". I think that during that time, there was really no policy available to new users. They came to MSO, saw it empty, and fired away. The community had to respond to a spike of that type of activity and kind of returned fire. Luckily the meta here is building up again, and we don't have a measly 100 questions to reference anymore.

Comment: [Average number of undeleted questions per day per month since site inception](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215578/average-number-of-undeleted-questions-per-day-per-month-since-site-inception#graph).

Comment: Once again, you guys pick out the wrong tid-bit of the question. I make one mention of a question, the point I'm making is that this site is taking itself far too seriously, you're not making the site better by being this way. In fact, I guarantee that stackoverflow will be replaced with a better competitor within the next few years.

Comment: @Mike - You had asked about ways that new users could be educated as to the rules, and I was attempting to address that by pointing out ways that commenters were able to provide explanations. The second comment I highlight above is a good example of a polite comment that can educate people as to site conventions that might not be immediately obvious. That's one way we can improve rule visibility, and by providing polite comments I hope we can improve the civility of discussions. As I indicated, I too am concerned about an increase in hostility to others, and try to work to reduce that.

Answer (score 14):

### We already go out of our way to help new users learn the site's guidelines

Stack Overflow has [an entire Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) dedicated to helping people learn how to use the site. More often than not, I suspect that most people **never bother to read it**.

In the section about [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), it states the following:

> #### Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

You provided very little context to the link in your answer, [as Brad pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267953/456814):

> You're saying you want to obfuscate your strings?
>
> [Try this.](https://code.google.com/p/strenc/)

### Helping people who want to learn how to ask better questions

There's an Area 51 proposal currently incubating that has the mission statement of helping new Stack Overflow users write and ask better questions:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Stack Overflow Academy]

Comment: I like that the proposal does solve a problem. I would be a little interested to see how it develops, but if Jon Skeet posted a canonical answer, would everything on that site be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @TravisJ Jon Skeet does not get access- He'll give the newbies an example of awesome that they will not achieve for a long time, and further crush their spirits.

Comment: That proposal is closed now.

Comment: ... and now the proposal is deleted.